# Why did Cartoon Network never air the last four episodes of Zoids: Chaotic Century?

Tags: zoids

This question is on the fence between here and [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), but does anyone know why Cartoon Network never aired the final four episodes of Zoids: Chaotic Century?

I loved CC as a kid, and went to great lengths to watch every airing. I watched it when it was on in the afternoon, and I set my VHS to record it when it came on at 5am CST after [adult swim] ended for the night.

In all the times I watched it, I never saw [The Ancient Memory, The Zoid Eve, The Moment of Annihilation, or Return to Another Tomorrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Zoids:_Chaotic_Century_episodes). I have my own theories, but I don't want to poison the well and am hoping there actually is an official reason out there.

Comment: Of course, watching the English dub after 10 years also makes me realize how bad the voice acting is and how awful the ending was. Waited all these years for virtually nothing.

Comment: That's what subs are for

Comment: BUT(!) there was never a true subbed version of Zoids: Chaotic Century. The original had more scenes and completely different dialogue in Japanese, but when it was dubbed to English it was bastardized to make it kid-friendly.

Comment: It's about time to give this question the best answer it can get. There's no way to get this information without access to the Cartoon Network employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Final Battle aired [on 2002 May 2nd](http://epguides.com/Zoids/) and almost a year later The Ancient Memory (1) aired on 2003 January 4th with the other three episodes. It is possible that Cartoon Network did air the last four episodes, or that it was Network 10/TV3 in Australia/New Zealand, respectively.

There was definitely some sort of discrepancy that prevented Zoids: Chaotic Century from being shown from start to finish. Sadly, the only people who can answer this question are those that worked at Cartoon Network at the time.

Answer (score 0):

They actually did air the final four episodes. I remember watching it on Toonami. Usually the show ran in the mourning but Toonami for the last 4 epsiodes made it a special event. It took over the block for 2 hours I believe and they showed the last 4 episodes.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Please refrain from answering old questions when you have nothing to add or contradict to the already existing ones.